# OpenLdap - purpose of attrs=entry?

Tags: ldap, openldap

what's the difference between a) and b)?

a)

```
access to dn.regex="^ou=addressbook,cn=([^,]+),ou=people,dc=example,dc=com$" 
          attrs=entry
   by dn.exact,expand="cn=$1,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" read
   by group.exact="cn=itpeople,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com" write
   by users none
```

b)

```
access to dn.regex="^ou=addressbook,cn=([^,]+),ou=people,dc=example,dc=com$" 
   by dn.exact,expand="cn=$1,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" read
   by group.exact="cn=itpeople,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com" write
   by users non
```

Both seems to give same results (??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `attrs=<attrlist>` selects attributes the access control rule should apply to, where `<attrlist>` is a comma-separated list of attributes.

**ObjectClass** names may also be specified, which will affect all the attributes that are required and/or allowed by that objectClass.

Additionally, pseudo-attributes "**entry**" and "**children**" can be specified :

- `attrs=entry`: *access to the entry itself*.
- `attrs=children`: *access to the entry's children*.

I think there is no difference between a) and b) because `attrs` should fallback to default if not specified :

- a)`attrs=entry` => access to the matched entry itself.
- b) no attrs clause => `attrs=@extensibleObject` is implied by default, meaning that all attributes are addressed.

`@extensibleObject` covers everything, including the pseudo-attrs entry and children.

Comment: Thanks! You explained so clearly. You deserved the 50 points bounty!

Answer (score 0):

The first form allows access to entry itself as well as to its attributes. See [access](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapd.access&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.4-Release).

Comment: I think the 2nd form also allows access to entry. If not what's the purpose of the 'access to' statement? Sole purpose is to update entries